# Custom Path in Vaadin Hilla

Tags: vaadin, vite, hilla

I have few custom lit components which i would like to call with import path @custom/ in Hilla

tsconfig.json

```
"paths": {
     "@custom":["generated/jar-resources/custom"],
     "@custom/*":["generated/jar-resources/custom/*"],
     "@vaadin/flow-frontend": ["generated/jar-resources"],
      "@vaadin/flow-frontend/*": ["generated/jar-resources/*"],
      "Frontend/*": ["*"]
   }
```

Here iam successfully able to add and access the @custom path in lit element ,but when i am executing mvn spring-boot:run
I am getting error - failed to import @custom/file_name.ts . Does the file exist ?
How to resolve this issue in Hilla so Vite can recognize it ?

Hilla Version = 2.1.4
Vite Version = 4.4.0